# Is there any difference between "anyone" and "any one"?

Tags: differences, spacing

When I read books in English, I see sometimes there is a space between "any" and "one" and sometimes there is not any space. So, what is the difference between "anyone" and "any one"?

Comment: I am sure this has been asked before here. I trust you searched this platform before posting this question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The word `anyone` refers to a single person. If `any one` is used by itself, it means the same as `anyone`, but it is preferred for it to be spelled without the space. If `any one` is used with something else (e.g. `any one of them`) it can mean something completely different.

In summary, almost all the time you should use `anyone`, but `any one` is also an acceptable spelling.

Comment: This is wrong.  *Anyone* refers to a single person; *any one* refers to one member of any set, whether of persons or things.  In the sentence "I could not love anyone but you", only *anyone* will do.

Comment: That is what I said. "The word anyone refers to a single person." I said that anyone almost always is a replacement for any one, but not the other way around.

Comment: No, you said that "any one" is an acceptable spelling.  It is, but not for *anyone*.  I don't know how you came to the conclusion that you should use *anyone* "almost all the time."  The two have different meanings, and each should be used as is appropriate to the context.

Answer (score 9):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) states regarding [any one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anyone):

> "The two-word form **any one** is not the same as the one-word form **anyone**
> and the two forms cannot be used interchangeably. **Any one** means ‘any
> single (person or thing)’, as in: not more than twelve new members are
> admitted in **any one** year."

Meanwhile, the one word form [anyone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anyone) is defined as follows:

> ***anyone***
>
> Line breaks: any¦one Pronunciation: /ˈɛnɪwʌn/
>
> Definition of anyone in English: pronoun
>
> 1 [USUALLY WITH NEGATIVE OR IN QUESTIONS] Any person or people:
> *there wasn’t anyone there*
> *does anyone remember him?*
> *I was afraid to tell anyone*
>
> 1.1 [WITHOUT NEGATIVE] Used for emphasis:
> *anyone could do it*
>
> 2 A person of importance or authority:
> *they are read by anyone who’s anyone*